# "Because" to "use"; C++

Tags: c++, string, double

I am trying to create a simple program that accepts doubles and puts them into a vector. If the value is not a double, it checks to see if the value is Q and continues to run unless it is "Q".

Here is the code:

```
string str = "";

while (str != "Q")
    {
        double n;
        cin >> n;

        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin >> str;

            if (str != "Q")
                cout << "'" << str << "'" << " is invalid input. Please try again!" << endl;
        }

        else
            vec.push_back(n);
    }
```

It seems to work perfectly. However some characters (b, e, c, a, etc.), will be skipped over when trying to output str. For instance, when I type in `because`, `str` outputs `use`.

I also find it really strange that when I change `n` from a `double` to an `int`, all characters are found (Input = `because` and `str` outputs `because`).

Is there something I am missing? Is this not an acceptable way to examine the output if it isn't a double?

Thanks!

Comment: `if(cin >> n) vec.pushBack(n) else { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Just kidding, I forgot I changed n to an int. Still does not work even as so. @Borgleader

Comment: Just an observation, the skipped characters are all hex digits.

Comment: The problem is it tried to parse the beginning of because, and wasn't able to, that part of the input was consumed, and AFAIK you can't get it back. There's probably a solution for this but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: +1 @user515430. Thats what I thought as well. But I didn't know why it would get rid of the characters that are hex.

Comment: @Zack If your compiler supports hex input for floating-point numbers that would be correct behavior.

Comment: @Borgleader +1. That seems to be the issue. I tried "zbeca" and the string outputted correctly. The problem is that N has to be a double as it needs to read decimals.

Comment: I also want to point out that when I type in "beca" it still hits cin.fail() and does not register as a number. Could this be because of the null terminator?? Just a thought...

Comment: It seems like the compiler is trying to parse an hexadecimal floating point (an intriguing C99 feature imported in C++11 see [std::hexfloat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)). Anyway an hex float should be preceded by 0x or 0X.. so this is _odd_.

Comment: @Nicolas Plus there is `std::hex` for integral types, and the fact that (in OP's experiments) double and int behave differently is even stranger.

Comment: Update @leemes: I compiled this with g++ in Linux and everything works as expected. Which is also very very strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the user enters `because`, and you try to read it as a number with `cin >> n`, it *tries* doing so. It fails *at some point*, and consumed all the characters until the parse error (excluding). Only after consumption of these characters, it returns and marks the operation as failed (which you check with `cin.fail()`). Note that a floating point number can indeed contain hexadecimal characters, as they might be encoded in hexadecimal notation*.

Reading the number consumes some hex-digits which are part of the string you want to consume *if parsing the input as a number failed*. (Details see comments below question.)

A simple solution is to first try to read a `'q'` and only if *that fails*, read a number, and if *that also fails*, the user entered something unexpected.

You can look at the next character *without consuming* it (so it's still there for parsing the number in the case it wasn't a `'q'` using [`cin.peek()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek).

Example:

```
if (cin.peek() == 'q') {
    // really consume it, for the case you want to use cin later on again
    cin.get();
    // quit
} else if (cin >> n) {
    // process input n
} else {
    // handle user error; you can still get the whole line from cin
}
```

---

<sub>*) Two things are however strange and might be discussed in the comments: First, hexadecimal numbers should start with `0x`, so it should fail at the very first non-digit/non-sign character. Secondly, why does `int` then not also show this behavior? Integers can also be hex encoded, afaik.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

As comments suggested, your environment seems to be interpreting hex digits as floats, which is bizarre. What environment are you using?

I personally find iostreams' rules for when they stop reading to be very unintuitive. (For example, in GCC, your loop interprets "123abc" as "123" followed by an error.)  If you want to read a line of text then process it, how about doing it explicitly?

```
while (str != "Q") {
  getline(cin, str);

  // Use stringstream to process one line of text exactly.
  stringstream s(str);
  double n;
  s >> n;

  if (str == "Q") {
    break;
  } else if (s.fail() || !s.eof()) {
    cout << "'" << str << "'" << " is invalid input. Please try again!" << endl;
  } else {
    vec.push_back(n);
  }
}
```

[Boost.Lexical_Cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) can make this easier.

Comment: I am using Xcode which seems to be using Apple's LLVM compiler. However, I tried compiling with g++ and it still did the same thing.